# SQL Query - Complex, not too sure where to start

Tags: sql

My apologies about the crappy title, but I am at a complete lost of where to start with this one

I have two tables  The first table just has customer ids  the second table has a list of interactions we have had with each customer  This includes interactions pertaining to appointments as well as a bunch of interaction types, most of which we don't call about

For each customer, we want to the date & description of their last appointment related interaction (whether it is canceled, scheduled, or had) as well as the date of the last prescription refill, if it exists

**Table_1**

```
User_ID    
-------
  001 
  002 
  003
```

**Table_2**

```
User_ID    Date         Interaction
------------------------------------------------------
  001       1/21/2015   Canceled Appointment
  001      12/09/2014   Scheduled Appointment
  001      12/01/2014   Called to Refill Prescription
  002       2/1/2015    Had Appointment
  002      12/2/2014    Called About Symptoms
  002      11/18/2014   Scheduled Appointment
  003       2/1/2015    Called to Refill Prescription
  003      11/28/2014   Had Appointment
```

**Desired output**

```
User_ID   Date         Appointment_Details      Prescription Refill Date
------------------------------------------------------------------------
 001       1/21/2015   Canceled Appointment     12/01/2014
 002       2/1/2015    Had Appointment          n/a
 003      11/28/2014   Had Appointment          2/1/2015
```

Comment: start pivot concept sql

Comment: Which [tag:rdbms] are you using?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: First at all, What is the RDBMS??

Comment: @chancrovsky, RDBMS stands fro Relational Database Management System. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database_management_system

Comment: Sorry, I mean "Which RDBMS is @user5879384  using ?

Answer (score 2):

Best to solve this in three steps:

For each User_ID, select the last record where the interaction is in the list "Cancelled Appointment", "Scheduled Appointment", or "Had Appointment". To do this we can use a Correlated Subquery to find the max(date) for each user_id where the interaction is in that list.

```
SELECT 
    user_id,
    DATE,
    interaction
FROM table_2 t2
WHERE DATE IN (
        SELECT max(DATE)
        FROM table_2
        WHERE t2.user_id = user_id
            AND Interaction IN (
                'Cancelled Appointment',
                'Scheduled Appointment',
                'Had Appointment'
                )
        )
```

For each User_ID, select the record where the interaction is "Called to refill Prescription". This one is a bit simple since need only to filter for "Called to refill prescription".

```
SELECT user_id, date FROM table_2 WHERE Interaction = 'Called To Refill Prescription'
```

Now we just join them together using a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, so we pick up all records from the first recordset, and only those that are matching from the second record set

```
SELECT
    t1.user_id,
    t1.date
    t1.Interaction as Appointment_Details
    t2.date as Prescription_Refill_Date
FROM
    (
        SELECT 
            user_id,
            DATE,
            interaction
        FROM table_2 t2
        WHERE DATE IN (
                SELECT max(DATE)
                FROM table_2
                WHERE t2.user_id = user_id
                    AND Interaction IN (
                        'Cancelled Appointment',
                        'Scheduled Appointment',
                        'Had Appointment'
                        )
                )   
    ) t1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT user_id, date FROM table_2 WHERE Interaction = 'Called To Refill Prescription') t3
        ON t1.user_id = t3.user_id
```

The big caveat here is that his really only works if the user_id shows up with on full set (a series of scheduled/cancelled/had appointments and a single "Called to refill Prescription"). Things will get a bit messier if it's necessary to show a user_id through multiple visits and multiple prescription refills. Also, if the scheduled and cancelled or scheduled and had an appointment on the same date, you will get duplicates back. This is because there is no logic stated that says which thing happened last. Either way, this should get you in the ballpark.

Comment: On the LEFT OUTER JOIN you need to SELECT max(date).
I am still thinking how to avoid duplicates in the main query.

Comment: That would be nice to insure that only the last set of interactions was taken into consideration. Unless, the person requested a refill, then a year later had an appointment, in which case you probably wouldn't want those interactions related. I've done similar logic where there is a lifecycle to a set of interactions, then a period passes, then a new lifecycle starts, but it was in Teradata where PERIOD logic and Window Functions make things a little easier.

Comment: Hi Nevill, see my complete answer below. I will give you credit though for the start too.

Your last comment could be done too, by adding to the left outer join a where condition, where you specify that max(date) should be greater than current date - 1 year.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it if you are using sql server:

Creating Sample Data:

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp1 ([User_ID] VARCHAR(5) )
INSERT INTO #Temp1
VALUES('001'),('002'),('003')

CREATE TABLE #Temp2 ([User_ID] VARCHAR(5),[Date] DATE, Interaction VARCHAR(50))
INSERT INTO #Temp2
VALUES('001','1/21/2015','Canceled Appointment'),

('001','12/09/2014','Scheduled Appointment'),

('001','12/01/2014','Called to Refill Prescription'),

('002','2/1/2015','Had Appointment'),

('002','12/2/2014','Called About Symptoms'),

('002','11/18/2014','Scheduled Appointment'),

('003','2/1/2015','Called to Refill Prescription'),

('003','11/28/2014','Had Appointment')
```

Query using [PIVOT](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx):

```
    SELECT  [User_ID],
       COALESCE([Had Appointment], [Canceled Appointment]) AS [Date],
       CASE  WHEN [Had Appointment] IS NULL AND [Canceled Appointment] IS NOT NULL THEN 'Canceled Appointment' 
             WHEN [Had Appointment] IS NOT NULL AND [Canceled Appointment] IS NULL THEN 'Had Appointment ' 
       END AS [Appointment_Details], 
       [Called to Refill Prescription]
FROM 
(   SELECT *
    FROM #Temp2 AS B ) p
PIVOT
(   MIN([Date] )
    FOR [Interaction] IN    (   [Had Appointment],[Canceled Appointment],
       [Scheduled Appointment],
       [Called to Refill Prescription]  )
) AS pvt
```

Result:

[image]

If you want the date format to show as US format dd/MM/yy then you can convert them to varchar `CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),<your column name>,1)`:

```
SELECT  [User_ID],
       CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),COALESCE([Had Appointment], [Canceled Appointment]),1) AS [Date],
       CASE  WHEN [Had Appointment] IS NULL AND [Canceled Appointment] IS NOT NULL THEN 'Canceled Appointment' 
             WHEN [Had Appointment] IS NOT NULL AND [Canceled Appointment] IS NULL THEN 'Had Appointment ' 
       END AS [Appointment_Details], 
       CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),[Called to Refill Prescription],1) AS [Called to Refill Prescription]
FROM 
(   SELECT *
    FROM #Temp2 AS B ) p
PIVOT
(   MIN([Date] )
    FOR [Interaction] IN    (   [Had Appointment],[Canceled Appointment],
       [Scheduled Appointment],
       [Called to Refill Prescription]  )
) AS pvt
```

Results:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    t1.user_id,
    t1.date
    t1.Interaction as Appointment_Details
    t2.date as Prescription_Refill_Date
FROM
    (
        SELECT 
            user_id,
            DATE,
            interaction
        FROM table_2 t2
        WHERE DATE IN (
                SELECT max(DATE)
                FROM table_2
                WHERE t2.user_id = user_id
                    AND Interaction IN (
                        'Cancelled Appointment',
                        'Scheduled Appointment',
                        'Had Appointment'
                        )
                )
            AND Interaction IN (
                SELECT max(Interaction)
                FROM table_2
                WHERE t2.user_id = user_id
                    AND Interaction IN (
                        'Cancelled Appointment',
                        'Scheduled Appointment',
                        'Had Appointment'
                        )
                    AND DATE = t2.date
                )      
    ) t1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT max(date) FROM table_2 
                      WHERE Interaction = 'Called To Refill Prescription') t3
            ON t1.user_id = t3.user_id
```

This is the answer from Nevill including avoiding duplicates.
You could either choose max(interaction) or min(interaction) as you prefer the order in which Cancelled, Had or Scheduled appointment would show. The only this is you cannot get Had if all three are there on the same date.

Surely it can be done with a CASE statement, but that makes the query even more complex.

Comment: As Nevill suggested it the LEFT OUTER JOIN could be changed into...

LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT max(date) FROM table_2 
                      WHERE Interaction = 'Called To Refill Prescription' and max(date) > current date - 1 year) t3
            ON t1.user_id = t3.user_id

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  t.[User_ID],
        t.[Date],
        t.[Interaction] [Appointment_Details],
        p.[Prescription Refill Date]
FROM    (SELECT Table_2.*,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Table_1.[User_ID] ORDER BY Table_2.[Date] DESC) Rn
         FROM   Table_1
                JOIN Table_2 ON Table_1.[User_ID] = Table_2.[User_ID]
         WHERE  [Interaction] IN ('Canceled Appointment', 'Scheduled Appointment', 'Had Appointment')
        ) t
        OUTER APPLY (SELECT MAX([Date]) [Prescription Refill Date]
                     FROM   Table_2
                     WHERE  t.[User_ID] = Table_2.[User_ID]
                            AND [Interaction] = 'Called to Refill Prescription'
                    ) p
WHERE   t.Rn = 1
```