# Joining upon one item in the table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 3 tables that are being joined upon (Table1, Table2, & Table 3). Lets say there are 40 rows in table3. 10 of those rows have a state code of 220. Bob lives in state code 220. It should then display the 10 rows in table3 of the statecode of 220 since the name is 'Bob'. The tables linking between table1 and table3 are name & statecode. I have come up with this query but am having issues if there are multiple Bob records in table A. This causes it to show duplicate rows. How could I fix this so that only one of the Bob names are used as bobs state code is 220? I am using Microsoft Sql Server

```
SELECT
            C.*
    FROM
            [Table1] A
       JOIN
            [Table2] B
                ON A.[Name] = B.[Name]
       JOIN
            [Table3] C
                ON B.[StateCode] = C.[StateCode]
    WHERE
            A.[Name] = 'Bob';
```

How each table is set up:

Table1 columns

```
name | email | phone
```

Table2 columns

```
name | statecode | company
```

Table3 columns

```
amount | statecode | average
```

Comment: It's hard to answer since you explanation of your table structure is difficult to process. It would probably be best if you showed us a quick example records for each table [kind of like in this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35439655/sql-query-complex-not-too-sure-where-to-start/35440097#35440097).. but... I'm betting that you could just change your first line from `SELECT` to `SELECT DISTINCT`

Comment: Try [SELECT DISTINCT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187731.aspx) combined with [LEFT JOIN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208894(v=office.12).aspx).

Comment: You should also add `AND B.[StateCode] = 220`. If you have multiple `Bob` in other states.

Comment: Without visibility of the data in those tables we can only guess. To get the best answer provide a few rows of data from each table. Anything private in that data can be omitted or changed. Please note that while **select distinct** might solve this problem it isn't a panacea and not something to avoid if possible.

Comment: @JNevill I have added better displayable structure. This is purely an example I have thrown together and have no real raw data for it. Going off of my question, I obtain someones name, find the state code in table 2 due to the name join, and then find all of the amount/averages in table 3, based off the state codes. I'm trying make a n:n into a 1:n. I'll try your tip. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you actually do not make use of any other attributes from `A`; then your query could also look like the following, where duplicate `Bob`'s in table `A` are not considered at all:

```sql
SELECT
            C.*
    FROM
            [Table2] B
       JOIN
            [Table3] C
                ON B.[StateCode] = C.[StateCode]
    WHERE
            B.[Name] = 'Bob';
```

You still may receive duplicates if table `B` contains more than one `Bob` or if table `C` contains more than one entry with `C.StateCode=220`; But that's not part of your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Distinct** but i would not recommend that option in this case.
You should not rely on name for joining two tables and you should have a **primary key** as name is not unique.
 Is it possible to change your table structure and add some useful columns?

Comment: Sadly I am not able to change the table structure. This is why I am trying to make the best out of what I have. I have tried distinct, but with Table1 have thousands & thousands of rows, it's not really working efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

If you have duplicate records in a table, a join will duplicate the output; that's just how they work.

Agree with KD that best practice is to keep the keys unique; however, using a subquery instead of a join may be a workaround:

```
select * from Table3  
where StateCode in (select StateCode from table2
                    where Name in (select Name from table1))
```

To understand how it works, start from the last query:

- select distinct name from table1 gets a list of all of the names in
  Table 1
- select statecode from table2 where name in... uses that list to
  select the StateCodes
- select * from Table3 where statecode in... pulls the records from
  table1 with those statecodes.

If you want to use the Where clause to select specific names, add it to the innermost query.